# how can I print unique code according to the loop if there is the same value?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

how can I print unique code according to the loop if there is the same value?

```
FullChar = 'CEFLMPRTVWXYK0123456789'
total = 1000
count = 10
count = int(count)
entries = []
bcd = ""
flg = ""
rll = ""

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="192.168.13.10",database="postgres", port="5432", user="postgres", password="potatona1")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    def inputDatabase(data):
        postgres_insert_query = """INSERT INTO unique_code(unique_code, barcode, flag, roll) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
        cursor.executemany(postgres_insert_query, data)
        conn.commit()


    for i in range(5):
        for x in range(total):    # banyaknya code yang di print
            unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(FullChar, count - 1))
            unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(unique_code, len(unique_code)))

        entry = (unique_code, bcd, flg, rll)
        entries.append(entry)

        inputDatabase(entries)
        print(i)

    count = cursor.rowcount
    print (count, "Record inserted successfully into mobile table")

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
    conn.rollback()
```

exmp : 
if this code MTY9X4L2E show up again/ duplicate, the loop will stop
and i get this message
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_code_pkey"

Answer (score 1):

To keep track of unique values, use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

```
unique_codes = set()
...
for i in range(5):
    for x in range(total):    # banyaknya code yang di print
        unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(FullChar, count - 1))
        unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(unique_code, len(unique_code)))
    if unique_code in unique_codes:
        # The unique code has already been used.
        # Do something?
    else:
        # Add the code to the set of used codes.
        unique_codes.add(unique_code)
```

It's not very clear what those loops are doing; `unique_code` gets overwritten in every iteration of the inner loop.

The example code has another problem: the `entries` list is never cleared, so the second iteration of the outer loop will cause a duplicate key error because `entries` contains not only the new data but also the data from the previous iteration.  `entries` should be cleared or reinitialised after each call to `inputDatabase`.

```
inputDatabase(entries)
entries.clear()
```